# realce de rango de grises -- vision artificial

Tags: python, python-3.x

a. Escriba una función que permita resaltar un rango de grises específico en una imagen. La función debe
recibir como parámetros de entrada: una imagen en escala de grises (uint8), el parámetro A y B que
define el rango de valores que la función va a resaltar. A y B deben ser positivo y menores a 255. La
imagen de salida será una imagen en blanco y negro; los pixeles blancos corresponderán a los pixeles
con valores entre A y B en la imagen de entrada, y los pixeles negros a todos los demás pixeles.

b. Seleccione una imagen a color, transforme la imagen a escala de grises y aplique el realce de rango de
grises para los siguientes valores de A y B: [A, B] = {[20 240], [40 200], [80 180], [100 150], [120
135]}.

Hola nuevamente, esta vez es un punto de vision artificial donde se tiene que hacer un realce de grises. La cuestion es que entiendo muy poco. Mas o menos entiendo que se coge una imagen y lo que esta en color negro lo vuelve en blanco y lo blanco lo vuelve a negro. He buscado en Google pero no es muy entendible si alguien supiera como explicarme le agradeceria.

-- El codigo que estamos implementando es este:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sys
sys.path.append('/media/basilio/ADATA UFD/VAI92/Code/')
import my_linealT as trans 

Im_g = Image.open('img2.jpg').convert('L')
Im_ga = np.array(Im_g)
a = np.array([1, 1, 1])
p1 = np.array([50, 125])
p2 = np.array([200, 225])
Im2 = trans.my_linealTrozos(Im_ga,a,p1,p2)

plt.gray()
plt.imshow(np.uint8(Im_ga))
plt.axis("off")

plt.figure()
plt.gray()
plt.imshow(Im2)
plt.axis("off")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al usar PIL para acceder a los pixeles debes usar el método load(), despues iterar usando el atributo size  y si estan en el rango establecerlos a 255 es el color blanco y 0 es el color negro.

```
from PIL import Image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def resaltar(imagen, rango):
    _from, _to = rango
    pixels = imagen.load()
    w, h = imagen.size
    for i in range(w):
        for j in range(h):
            pixels[i, j] = 0 if  _from <= pixels[i, j] <= _to else 255

image_rgb= Image.open('image.png')
image_gray = image_rgb.convert('L')
resaltar(image_gray, [0, 100])
plt.imshow(image_gray)
plt.show()
```

**image.png**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!